# How to convert a base64 string that is included in a JSON string

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, angular

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addItem()
    {
        var tae = Request.Form[0];
        var ctx = new Models.CangsODEntities4();

        Models.Item item= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Item>(tae);

        ctx.Items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        Response.StatusCode = 200; 

        return Content(item.itemID.ToString());
    }
```

This is my post method but there seems to be an error of not being able to add in `ctx.Items.Add(item)` because of the base64 string.

```
 getBase64(file : File ){
         var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
           // console.log(reader);
           // console.log(typeof reader.result);
            ProductService.imgstring=reader.result.split(',')[1];           
            //console.log(this.imgstring);
        }.bind(this);
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);

        };


  }

  addItem(data:any,pic:File){
   // console.log(data);
   this.getBase64(pic["0"]);
   setTimeout (() => {
        //data["picture"]=this.getBase64(pic["0"]);

        console.log(ProductService.imgstring);
        data["picture"]=ProductService.imgstring;
        console.log(data);
         let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let reqopt = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        })
        this._http.post(this._productAddUrl,JSON.stringify(data), reqopt).subscribe(function(res){
            this.response=res;
            alert(this.response);
        });

    }, 5000)
```

And this is what I did on the angular side. For passing the JSON string.

[image]

Do I need to have another method that converts the base64 string? Or is there any way to include it in my post method?

```
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int itemQuantityStored { get; set; }
    public decimal itemPrice { get; set; }
    public int purchaseCount { get; set; }
    public byte[] picture { get; set; }
```

This is the **Models.Item** class

Comment: Please post the error message. What data is the C# backend receiving?

Comment: Just posted the error message @JulienAmbos. It is suppose to receive a JSON string since i used stringify.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `tae`? What does the `Models.Item` class look like?

Comment: @JulienAmbos its the headers. Just edited it, the Models.Item is in there.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint on that line and tell me, before the exception gets thrown, what the value of the variable `tae` is? Or are you really trying to parse the headers into the Models.item class?